# Connect Vehicle Entity to Product Entity in ProductinOrder Entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, entity

I'm building a shop for a roadhelp company an I'm stuck on how to connect two of my Entities in the best way.

### Here is a brief summary of the Entities:

**Orders**: This is where all the basic order data is. (*PK* = orderid, ipaddress, etc)

**Product**: This contains a productid as *PK*, name, price etc. This can be a subscription to a Roadhelp product but it can also be a showel you buy together with a subscription.

**ProductinOrders**: This contains foreign keys to **Orders** and **Product**. The *PK* is orderid, productid and weight. It also contains a field for whether or not the product can be removed from the order.

And now for the "bastard"...

I also have a **Vehicle** Entity where the *PK* are orderid (from Orders) and Licenseplate. The Entity contains data like Make, Model, Variant etc. (This data is retrieved when the customer enters the licenseplate in the form).

The customer should be able to buy as many subscriptions as he/she wants to in the same "flow". Therefore I need to keep **Vehicle** and the subscription **Product** in the **ProductinOrders** in sync.

To make a long story short... *sigh*

When the customer as entered the Licenseplate I need to be able to connect the licenseplate with a specific product.

Regards,
Lars Hansen

Comment: @Kevinrob - yes, I'm using ORM in the Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is that you should connect your entities like in real world.
So: Orders ManyToMany Product, User OneToMany/ManyToMany Vehicle (it depends), Vehicle ManytoMany Product

You'll be able to find Vehicle for signed User, Products for the specified Vehicle and also Products in the specified Order

Of course you have to think about updating and persisting both sides of relatinships of entites in your entities methods.

Comment: Hi @Jan-Rydrych - I'm not sure I follow you on the "Product User" part on line 2?

Comment: Sorry, i have typo in my answer

Comment: I think you're on to something here.

But I think the Vehicle < - > Product is onetomany - the Vehicle can only be linked with one Product.

Comment: And a vehicle can only belong to one customer but a customer can have multiple vehicles.

Comment: Same product cannot be for more vehicles? Snowchains, insurance, first aid kit? Relationship User <-> Vehicle depends on what you want. There can possibly be two customers for one vehicle (family car - husband and wife)

Comment: The Vehicle Entity is only needed when there is a Roadhelp subscription in the productinorder entity...

Comment: I understand - so "User OnetoMany Vehicle" should be o.k.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102712/discussion-between-lars-hansen-and-jan-rydrych).